# Sorting data numerically from a plist dictionary in a UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipicker

I'm using the following code to sort the results in a UIPicker. The results are coming randomly because I am using a dictionary / plist to store the data.

```
NSArray *components = [self.dobRangesDict allKeys];
NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
self.dates = sorted;
```

this sorts the data, but I'm looking to sort the data numerically. Any ideas how I might go about accomplishing this?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

My personal choice is to use `[components sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *a, NSString *b) { return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch]; }]`

Comment: thanks. i tried that but get a 'NSArray' may not respond to '-sortUsingComparator' warning and a crash. using:     NSArray *sorted = [components sortUsingComparator:^(NSString *a, NSString *b) { return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch]; }];

Comment: sorry, in your particular case you want sortedArrayUsingComparator. soryUsingComparator would be if it was an NSMutableArray

Comment: thanks again. I used:     NSArray *sorted = [components sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *a, NSString *b) { return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch]; }];
but am getting an error message "incompatible block pointer type initializing *int(^)(struct NSString *, struct NSString *)' expected NSComparator"

Comment: Are you trying to do this using GCC? That compiles fine under LLVM. Try [components sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *a, NSString *b) { return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch]; }];

Comment: yes GCC. i tried with LLVM and it compiled fine too. thanks for all your help